# Checking if script have loaded works sometimes

Tags: javascript, createjs

I'm having trouble checking if scripts have loaded.

I've tried to put a custom variable in the scripts and checking using .onload. I even set a timer that stops the inital function from firing but I get the following errors

> "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

the cursor in the console points to `new createjs.Container`

Below is the code so far:

This function uses .loaded and sets a var to true
The thing is that they are always true but I still get errors

```
unction politeInit(){
var s7Loaded, s6Loaded, s5Loaded, s4Loaded, s3Loaded, s2Loaded, s1Loaded;

var css = document.createElement('link');
css.setAttribute("rel","stylesheet");
css.setAttribute("type","text/css");
css.setAttribute("href","fonts/fonts.css");
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(css);

var s1 = document.createElement('script');
s1.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
s1.setAttribute("src","libs/easeljs-0.6.0.min.js");


var s2 = document.createElement('script');
s2.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
s2.setAttribute("src","libs/tweenjs-0.4.0.min.js");


var s3 = document.createElement('script');
s3.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
s3.setAttribute("src","libs/movieclip-0.6.0.min.js");


var s4 = document.createElement('script');
s4.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
s4.setAttribute("src","libs/preloadjs-0.3.0.min.js");


var s5 = document.createElement('script');
s5.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
s5.setAttribute("src","Mondeo_Lightning_728x90_V2.js");

var s6 = document.createElement('script');
s6.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
s6.setAttribute("src","setUpText.js");


var s7 = document.createElement('script');
s7.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
s7.setAttribute("src","main.js");

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s1); 
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s2);
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s3);
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s4);
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s5);
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s6);
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s7);

s1.onload = function(){
s1Loaded = true; 

}         
s2.onload = function(){
 s2Loaded = true; 

}        
s3.onload = function(){
 s3Loaded = true; 

}        
s4.onload = function(){
s4Loaded = true; 
}
s5.onload = function(){
 s5Loaded = true;
}



s6.onload = function(){
s6Loaded = true; 
}

s7.onload = function(){
s7Loaded = true; 
}



var timeout = 100; // 10 seconds timeout    
poll = function () {
setTimeout(function () {
timeout--;

if (s7Loaded && s6Loaded && s5Loaded && s4Loaded && s3Loaded && s2Loaded && s1Loaded) {
init();
}else if (timeout > 0) {
    poll();
}else {
  // External library failed to load
    }
}, 100);
};

poll();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the scripts to the body instead.

```
function politeInit () {
    /* ... */
    ["libs/easeljs-0.6.0.min.js",     "libs/tweenjs-0.4.0.min.js",
     "libs/movieclip-0.6.0.min.js",   "libs/preloadjs-0.3.0.min.js",
     "Mondeo_Lightning_728x90_V2.js", "setUpText.js", "main.js"].
    forEach(function (src) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = '' + src;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    });
}
```

Then, in `main.js` you should have an immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE) to start page execution.  However, any immediately-invoked scripts in the other js files may run concurrently in another "thread."  If you intend to use any of these scripts, you could incur a race condition.  If that's the case, alter those scripts to not be immediately-invoked and instead manually invoke them from `main.js`.  Here is what an IIFE looks like:

```
(function () {
    /* do stuff immediately */
})();
```

It can also look like this:

```
!function () { /* do stuff */ };
```

Comment: Hi Micah, Thanks for your time and very informative answer.

I encased all immediate functions within functions  - main.js is an immediate function and call all others from main.js but outside the of the main.js function

(Although I have treid inside too), but I'm still get an error in regards to one of the files it telling me the namespace "lib" is not defined

I add that this is the only error I'm getting now
Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you I managed to sort out the problem by waiting for the scripts to load one by one, thanks for your help